# Hello i am struggling to understand why it say constructor undefined java

Tags: java

I wrote three classes to be used in main, but when I call the constructor of Calculator with two parameter, it tells me that the constructor is undefined. When I checked the code it looked like everything was done correctly, and I still can't find the error. Is this because am calling two instance objects in another class parameter?

I get the below error:

```
Unresolved compilation problem: The constructor Calculator(Floor, Carpet) is undefined.
```

My main code is below:

```
Carpet carpet = new Carpet(3.5);
Floor floor = new Floor(2.75, 4.0); 
Calculator calculator = new Calculator(floor,carpet); // this line gives me the error
```

Calculator.java:

```
public class Calculator {

     private double floor;
     private double carpet;

     Calculator(double floor, double carpet) {
         this.carpet = carpet;
         this.floor = floor;
     }
     Calculator() {
         floor = 0.00;
         carpet = 0.00;
     }

     public double getTotalCost() {
         return (this.floor * this.carpet);
     }
 }
```

Floor.java:

```
 public class Floor {
     private double width;
     private double length;

     Floor() {}
     Floor(double width, double length) {
         this.length = length;
         this.width = width;
     }
     public void setWidth(double width) {
         if (this.width < 0) {
             this.width = 0;
         } else {
             this.width = width;
         }
     }
     public void setLength(double length) {
         if (this.length < 0) {
             this.length = 0;
         } else {
             this.length = length;
         }
     }
     public double getArea() {
         return (this.length * this.width);
     }
 }
```

Carpet.java:

```
 public class Carpet {

     private double cost;

     Carpet() {}
     Carpet(double cost) {
         this.cost = cost;
     }
     public void setCost(double cost) {
         if (cost < 0) {
             this.cost = 0;
         } else {
             this.cost = cost;
         }
     }
     public double getCost() {
         return this.cost;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the main class, also do you have packages defined?

Comment: Carpet carpet = new Carpet(3.5);
  Floor floor = new Floor(2.75, 4.0);
  Calculator calculator = new Calculator(floor,carpet);

Comment: What and where is the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Calculator(Floor, Carpet) is undefined. esclispe want me to use class of floor and carpet as paramater in calculator. instead of using my double

Comment: And what is unclear about that? _That_ specific constructor _is_ undefined. Where is your confusion?

Comment: why is it undefined? check the code and tell me what you see wrong

Comment: I see two constructors, one take no parameter and one taking two doubles. Just because you named them `floor` and `carpet` doesn't mean the types `Floor` or `Carpet` are accepted.

Comment: it wont let me pass in floor and carpet from the new instance created into calculator but i can pass number as double into calculator parameter.

Comment: Like I said, it takes doubles, not `Floor` or `Carpet`. Types matter you can't just mix them around.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor for `Calculator` calls for two `double` values. You passed objects of type `Carpet` and `Floor`. instead. Try editing your `Calculator` class to accept those types, rather than `double` values.

```
private Floor floor;
private Carpet carpet;

Calculator(Floor floor, Carpet carpet) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.carpet = carpet;
    this.floor = floor;
}
```

You should also revise `getTotalCost()` to the below method:

```
public double getTotalCost() {
    return this.carpet.getCost() * this.floor.getArea();
}
```

Comment: but why must i pass the class as of FLOOR AND CAPTAL, aS A parameter instead of double when calling the calculator in the main. also why cant i pass two instance variable of floor and carpet in calculator?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructors are not public, they are defined as a `package private`. That might be the problem.

Comment: It still the same it all on public all my constructor

Comment: am sure you can see am using double in the parameter of calculator ?

Comment: I believe that all the classed dealt with here are in the same package. I do not think this is the problem.